# Google Maps API V3 UK Districts

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I'm trying to set a border around some districts in the UK, similar to how Google do it on here : http://g.co/maps/wbtj3

Does Google release the latitude and longitude data for districts? I cannot see anything in the API which will allow me to search for a district and get the data for it to display on the map.

Is there an easy way to "extract" the latitude and longitude data for a district for use in an polygon?

It seems that American data is easier to find (http://econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml) or am I not looking hard enough?

Appreciate any advice :).

**Edit:** I believe it's pretty new as I can't find much info about it "highlighted search results" - http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2012/01/highlighted-search-results-in-google.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenStreetMap has boundary data for [English Counties](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/English_Counties) which are free to use and available in multiple formats.

As far as I know, Google does not provide any underlying map data via an API.

Comment: That seems to be what I want, I can see the bounds of "Lincolnshire" although export to XML doesn't give me the boundaries? Thanks.

Comment: Try the GPX file.  That can be imported into Google Earth or converted to other formats by applications like GPSBabel, GPS Visualizer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Getting co-ordinates for a polygon would require GIS files and a GIS software like MapInfo to read.

My advice would be visit this site;

http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showthreaded&Number=332073

Download the KML file which has the district boundaries of UK counties and then use it in either google earth or fusion tables.

Finding out what your using these for may help get a better answer...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm allowing users to "map" certain things on google maps which should only be allowed in their district. So I want to highlight there distrct on the map and limit the drawing area to their district.

Comment: Also, if your map is on a public server, you can have it show KML files.  E.g., the KMZ file @Elliot mentioned : http://g.co/maps/953wr .

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to figure out the polygon coordinates yourself.  If it was only for a few districts, maybe not such an onerous task.  But if it's for the whole of the UK...  Here's a website that will quickly give you coordinates as you draw polygons:
http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html

Answer (score 0):

afaik google doesn't offer such service in his APIs. But you could download you file of interest here: http://www.gadm.org/country
if you grab it as kml, you could easily import it into Google-Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this thread - you may have solved the problem a long time ago, but this may be useful:
http://mapit.mysociety.org/

Comment: Thanks for joining us at SO Chris.  We encourage people to summarize the information when they post a link.  That way, if the link ever goes stale in the future, the essence of the answer will still be useful.